# Given a joint Laplace-Stieltjes transform, is it possible to find a joint PDF?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, laplace-transform, fourier-transform, inverse-laplace

If we have a joint Laplace-Stieltjes transform (or MGF or characteristic function) of some independent nonnegative continuous random variables $X = (X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$ defined on $[0,\infty)$, the LST would be $L(t)=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-t\cdot X}\right]=L_{X_1}(t_1)\cdots L_{X_n}(t_n)$. Under certain conditions, we can do inverse Laplace transforms to find marginal PDFs, which we can multiply to get the joint PDF.

If the $X_j$'s are dependent random variables, we cannot carry out most of these steps. Is there some way to find the joint PDF from a Laplace-Stieltjes transform (or MGF or CF)?

I'm not sure if perhaps it can be done analytically if the LST is simple enough or if numerical inversions are required, or if some of these are approaches are viable under certain assumptions.

Thank you!

Comment: I’m just curious if Laplace-Stieltjes transform is Laplace transform using Riemann-Stieltjes integral, where we can introduce Dirac function since in $\int fdg$ g can be discontinuous?

Comment: Well, the expectation of a random variable X is defined to be a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral with respect to its distribution function, so sometimes it coincides with a Riemann integral.

If f is measurable, the expectation of f(X) is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral of f(x) with respect to the distribution function of X.

The Laplace-Stieltjes transform is the expected value of exp(-tX), so it falls into that category, and so it can reduce to an ordinary Laplace transform of a pdf depending on the distribution function.

Comment: So the expectation is $\int f(X)dF(X)$, where F'(x) is the usual probability function, and f(X) is value at X? L transform is to transform f(X) to another function of t (where t is a parameter of transformation) https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html, e.g. Bessel functions and trig functions are transformed to algebraic expression of t. and L-S transform is $\int e^{-tX}dF(X)$, or $\int f(X)e^{-tX}dF(X)$, i.e. to transform f(X) to a function of t w.r.t. a distribution of X. If the distribution is linear, then L-S transform is L transform.

Comment: And Laplace transform can be understood as transform the function from its original domain (like time) to another domain and therefore makes explicit some other characteristics of the function, like frequency or periods or power, as seen in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html

Comment: By f, I only meant some arbitrary measurable function--for example, f(x) = exp(-tx) for the Laplace-Stieltjes transform.

If I can write down a single Laplace-Stieltjes transform $\int e^{-tX}dF(X)$, there's lots we can do, especially if F has enough regularity. We can take inverses explicitly or numerically, etc.

What I'm not sure how to do, or if it's possible, is to take $\int\int e^{-t_1X_1-t_2X_2} dF(X_1,X_2)$ with this F being the joint distribution function where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are dependent and find the joint probability density.